# C# Delete one of two successive and same lines in a list

Tags: c#, list

how can i delete one of two same successive lines in a list?
For example:

```
load
testtest
cd /abc
cd /abc
testtest
exit
cd /abc
```

In this case ONLY line three OR four.The lists have about 50000 lines, so it is also about speed.
Do you have an idea?

Thank you!

Homeros

Comment: What have you tried so far? The simplest solution to come to mind is to use a for loop to check if __nth__ and __nth +1__ elements are the same and then remove one of them. However, you would need to work on a copy of the list, since iterating over a changing list is disallowed. You could use LINQ as well.

Comment: 50k is not a lot at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to look at the last added element in the second list:

```
var secondList = new List<string>(firstList.Count){ firstList[0] };

foreach(string next in firstList.Skip(1))
    if(secondList.Last() != next)
        secondList.Add(next);
```

Since you wanted to *delete* the duplicates you have to assign this new list to the old variable:

```
firstList = secondList;
```

This approach is more efficient than deleting from a list.

Side-note: since `Enumerable.Last` is optimized for collections with an indexer(`IList<T>`), is is as efficient as `secondList[secondList.Count-1]`, but more readable.

Answer (score 0):

user a reverse for-loop and check the adjacent elements:

```
List<string> list =  new List<string>();

for (int i = list.Count-1; i > 0 ; i--)
{
    if (list[i] == list[i-1])
    {
        list.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

the reverse version is advantageous here, because the list might shrink in size with every removed element

Answer (score 0):

I would first split the list, then use LINQ to only select items that don't have the same previous item:

```
string[] source = text.Split(Environment.NewLine);

var list = source.Select((l, idx) => new { Line = l, Index = idx } )
                 .Where(x => x.Index == 0 || source[x.Index - 1] != x.Line)
                 .Select(x => x.Line)
                 .ToList() // materialize
                 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

O(n) as extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<string> RemoveSameSuccessiveItems(this IEnumerable<string> items)
{  
    string previousItem = null;
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        if (item.Equals(previousItem) == false)
        {
            previousItem = item;
            yield item;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it

```
lines = lines.RemoveSameSuccessiveItems();
```

Comment: `if (item.Equals(previousItem) == false)` > `if (!item.Equals(previousItem))`

Comment: Will work too - but I prefer to write `== false` for negation condition - easy to read in  the head then `!` prefix